# Convert Numbers to Letters within a data variable column

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a set of variables in my data file from numbers to letters, such that every 2 is b every 3 is c and so on.

I have tried the following code and receive the error listed below:

```
B3_cfile$Row  <- as.character(LETTERS(B3_cfile$Row))
```

Error: could not find function LETTERS

My code may also be incorrect as I am very new to R. However my understanding is that LETTERS is a function built into R that does not require an additional package.

Comment: `LETTERS[B3_cfile$Row]`

Answer (score 0):

As Phil writes in the comment, `LETTERS` is not a function, but a vector (an array), to access the content, you need to use brackets: `LETTERS[B3_cfile$Row]`

if you are new to R, you can check the types easily as:
`str(LETTERS)`